# Pie chart data not get updated over REST call

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, pie-chart, nvd3.js

I'm using d3 pie chart in my angular app as follows,

```
                      <nvd3-pie-chart
                                data="collectedData"
                                id="piechart1"
                                width="380"
                                height="420"
                                x="xFunction()"
                                y="yFunction()"
                                tooltips="true"
                                donut="true"
                                donutRatio=".015"
                                color="colorFunctionPie()">
                            <svg height="230"></svg>
                        </nvd3-pie-chart>
```

values for "collectedData" is added as follows,

```
scope.collectedData=[{key:"one",y:10}];
scope.collectedData.push({key:"two",y:10});
```

this works fine, but when I use REST call in between those two values to fetch more values as follows,

```
for(var i=0;i<tenantNames.length;i++){
            resourceFactory.noOfClientsResource.get({reportDate:'2014-07-08',reportName:'Number of Clients',tenantIdentifier:tenantNames[i]},function (data) {
                scope.collectedData.push({key:data.tenantIdentifier,y:data.dataPointValues[0].dataPointValues[0]});

            });
            }
```

Pie chart only displays previous two values("one" and "two"), But `Console.log(scope.collectedData);` will print all four values including values from REST call. 
How can I update pie chart data including values from REST call?

Comment: Have you tried scope.$apply()? The request might be outside the scope of the digest cycle.

Comment: true. scope.$apply();

Comment: it gives an error saying "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress"

Comment: just after the line "scope.collectedData.push({key:data.tenantIdentifier,y:data.dataPointValues[0].dataPointValues[0]});"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is that you can get the data before the template loads using angular routeProvider parameter resolve.

Get the initial data

```
resolve: {
    initialData: function(newsControllerInitialData){
        return data;
    }
}
```

Feed the initial data to the graph

```
app.controller("appController", function ($scope, initialData) {
    $scope.collectedData = initialData;
});
```

By this approach you will not have to redraw the graph multiple times. And resoling the data is besst approach as we get the data before template loads.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Chann said, add `scope.$apply` after your `scope.collectedData.push` line.

Or, wrap said line in `scope.$apply`, like so:

```
scope.$apply(function () {
  scope.collectedData.push({key:data.tenantIdentifier,y:data.dataPointValues[0].dataPointValues[ 0]});
});
```